# How to include a component in two separate modules?

Tags: angular, angular-module

I have two modules: `ItemsListModule` and `SearchModule`.

`ItemsListModule` wraps `ItemsListComponent`, and `SearchModule` wraps `SearchComponent`.

`ItemsList` is used on a page to show a list of items, and I'd also like to use it in `Search` to show the list of results. In other words: within `SearchComponent`, I'd like to use `ItemsListComponent` as well.

```
// SearchModule
@NgModule({
  declarations: [SearchComponent],
  imports: [SearchRoutingModule],
})

// ItemsListModule
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ItemsListComponent],
  imports: [],
})

// AppModule
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [ItemsListModule, SearchModule],
})
```

When I then use `<my-items-list>` within `SearchComponent`'s template, I am getting an error that the component is unknown and please verify it is part of the `SearchModule`. If I add it to the `SearchModule`'s imports, I get the same error message.

Why ? How do I reuse `ItemsList` to show my search results? (Angular 8.3)

Comment: just add `ItemsListComponent` to SearchModule->declarations

Comment: add `ItemsListComponent` in `entrycomponents` in your `SearchModule`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export your `ItemListComponent` from `ItemListModule` and import this module in `SearchModule`

*SearchModule*

```js
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [SearchComponent],
      imports: [SearchRoutingModule, ItemListModule],
    })
```

*ItemsListModule*

```js
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [ItemListComponent],
      exports: [ItemListComponent]
    })
```

Comment: in `ItemsListModule` do you really need to declare ItemsListModule ??

Comment: To save time i copy pasted it from the question itself :P

Answer (score 2):

*ItemsListModule*

```js
        @NgModule({
          declarations: [ItemsListComponent], // declare Item list component here
          imports: [],
          exports: [ItemListComponent]
        })
```

*SearchModule*

```js
        @NgModule({
          declarations: [SearchComponent],
          imports: [SearchRoutingModule,
                    ItemsListModule], //  import ItemListModule Here

        })
```

> and try to use `<my-items-list>` in search.component.html, it will
>   work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `ItemsListComponent` in the `entrycomponents` in your `SearchModule`
like this

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [ 
   ItemsListComponent
],
entryComponents: [
    ItemsListComponent
  ]
})
```